# How do I get the state array of a child component to a parent component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, react-forms

I have a tags section in a form and I am rendering tags div from another component called `<StackTag/>`, I have a state array of tags in that component. And in my form onSubmit, I am creating an object of the form data. I am having trouble accessing the tags array from `<StackTag>` and pushing the tags into my form object.

```
 const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
...
         <input
          type='text'
          onKeyDown={handleTag}
          onChange={handleTag}
          value={currentTagText}
          placeholder='Type your interests here'
        />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.stacktags}>
        {tags.map((tag, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={classes.stackInput} key={index}>
              {tag}
              <button
                onClick={() => removeTag(index)}
                className={classes.tagCloseBtn}
              >
                x
              </button>
```

And in my Form component,

```
  <div className={classes.interestDiv}>
      <label htmlFor='skills'>Skills</label>

      <StackTag />
    </div>
```

In my console, I can see the state of `<StackTag/>`, I can see the array with the tags, it is working, I tried different methods but I could not figure it out, I am using react-hook-form to get the form data using const

```
{ register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [result, setResult] = useState('');
...
{...register('name')}
```

How can I add the tags to my result object?

Comment: Did you add onSubmit to your form component?

Comment: The component state of `StackTag` is "private" in the sense that other React components can't just reach in and access it, this would break many abstractions. Pass a callback prop in to `StackTag` for it to pass it's state out, or move the `tags` state out to the parent component and pass both the `tags` and callback as props. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Yes onSubmit is in my form component, and the `<StackTag/>` is inside the Form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move state `[tags, setTags]` to the parent component. As for passing props down to the child, I can think of two options:

**Option 1: pass setTags down to child**

```
const StackTag = ({ tags, setTags }) => {
  const [currentTagText, setCurrentTagText] = useState("");

  const handleTag = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.value) {
      setTags((tags) => [...tags, e.target.value]);
      setCurrentTagText("");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  const removeTag = (index) => {
    setTags((tags) => tags.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onKeyDown={handleTag}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCurrentTagText(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={currentTagText}
        placeholder="Type your interests here"
      />
      {tags.map((tag, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {tag}
            <button type="button" onClick={() => removeTag(index)}>x</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default function Form() {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        console.log("Submitting Form with tags:", tags);
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <StackTag tags={tags} setTags={setTags} />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shamir-ogptl)

**Option 2: pass down handlers for the click and keydown:**

```
const StackTag = ({ tags, onTagAdd, onTagRemove }) => {
  const [currentTagText, setCurrentTagText] = useState("");

  const handleTag = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.value) {
      onTagAdd(e.target.value);
      setCurrentTagText("");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onKeyDown={handleTag}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCurrentTagText(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={currentTagText}
        placeholder="Type your interests here"
      />
      {tags.map((tag, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {tag}
            <button type="button" onClick={() => onTagRemove(index)}>
              x
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default function Form() {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        console.log("Submitting Form with tags:", tags);
        e.preventDefault();
      }}
    >
      <StackTag
        tags={tags}
        onTagAdd={(tag) => {
          setTags((tags) => [...tags, tag]);
        }}
        onTagRemove={(tag) => {
          setTags(tags.filter((val) => val !== tag));
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-hofstadter-wqxpw?file=/src/App.js)